# Enable a user option to override a value for a variable

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine returning three elements of an array. 
`return ($file[0], $file[2], $file[3]);` 
I am then assigning it to three variables. 
`my ($file1, $file2, $file3) = getFiles();`

This does exactly what's expected and assigns to each of the variables.

I now want to enable a user option to supply any of the files through the command line if they wish.

Here is what I did:

```
if(not defined $file1){$file1 = $file1;}
if (not defined $file2){$file2 = $file2;}
if (not defined $file3){$file3 = $file3;}
else {($file1, $file2, $file3) = @ARGV;}
```

This is the error I get when later trying to use that variable.

> Use of uninitialized value $file1 at script.pl line 40 
>   Use of uninitialized value $file2 at script.pl line 41 
>   Use of uninitialized value $file3 at script.pl line 42

How can I properly do this so that it keeps the same path unless a user passes one through command line?

Comment: What exactly does "I get errors" mean? The code in your question does not produce any error message when I include it in a script. And I don't see anything in your question about assigning a variable to itself. [mcve]

Comment: I've updated with more details. @KeithThompson

Comment: What do you expect `$file1 = $file1;` to do? If the initial value of `$file1` is `undef`, it's still going to be `undef` after the assignment.

Comment: So you want to use any filenames that user supplied instead of what the function returned (for _those_ names)?

Comment: "Uninitialized" really means "undefined", whether it's because you never assigned or value or for some other reason

Comment: @KeithThompson I thought using "if(defined $file1)" would mean that if there is a user input for it and if (not defined $file1) could be used if there is no user input through command line. I'm confused on how to properly syntax for command line arg options in code.

Comment: As for "_how to properly syntax for command line arg options_" --- need separate variables, for what the function returns and what is assigned by user input.  Or, need `if`-branches for all possibilties, like `if (not defined $file2) { (undef, $file2, undef) = getFiles() }`  (assign only to `$file2` and discard other returns from the function) -- but that would be a mess since there'd be a separate call for each possibilty (f1 and f2, f1 and f3, ...). Another good option is to rewrite the sub, so that it can take information about what filenames to return (or set, by reference).

Comment: `if (not defined $file1)` is perfectly fine. The problem is what you do if it's not defined. You probably want something like `if (not defined $file1) { $file1 = some_meaningful_value; }`. Your statement `$file1 = $file;` is guaranteed to be useless whether `$file1` is defined or not, regardless of the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the question as follows: allow for user input for (any of) three filenames, and then the ones that are supplied should override names that are anyway worked out otherwise.

There are two main components to this

- Need to provide named arguments for user input; how else are they going to give you the name for, say, file-2 only? That's solved nicely with the core module [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)
- Implement some logic that allows you to check what names have been supplied and assign the others. Use of extra (ancillary) variables makes that easier

A basic example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;

my ($fn1, $fn2, $fn3);

GetOptions('file1|f1=s' => \$fn1, 'file2|f2' => \$fn2, 'file3|f3' => \$fn3)
    or usage();

SET_NAMES: {
    my @fnames = getFiles();

    $fn1 //= $fnames[0];  #/
    $fn2 //= $fnames[1];  #/
    $fn3 //= $fnames[2];
};

say "Filenames:\n\t$fn1\n\t$fn2\n\t$fn3";


sub usage {
    say STDERR "Usage: $0 [-file1|f1 name] [-file2|f2 name] [-file3|f3 name]";
    exit;
}

sub getFiles { return qw(n1 n2 n3) }  # so that this program runs
```

This program can then be invoked as

```
script.pl --file2 name2
script.pl -f1 name1 -f3 name3   # etc
```

so with nice flexibility for how the arguments are given. See `Getopt::Long` docs.

The block `SET_NAMES` is used only to lexically isolate that code so that the temporary `@fname` isn't visible elsewhere.

As for filenames, we check each for whether it has been defined (by user input) and if not then the corresponding name from `getFiles` is assigned to it. This uses [defined-or operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or), `//=`.

There are of course a number of other ways to resolve this. Perhaps the best would be to modify the function itself so that it sets up names that *are* needed.

Comment: But when using Getopt, don't you still have to set the variables to @ARGV to be read through the command line? So either it reads in a user command or it uses the value assigned to it in the script.

Comment: The `Getopt::Long` assigns input for us, to variables given by `=> \$var`.  So, if user submitted name for file2 (first example invocation) then that (string `name2` in the example) is assigned to the variable `$fn2`.  Then later we check which ones were set that way, and those that weren't are set up by what the function returned.  So, in this example, in `$fn2 //= ...` the `$fn2` _has been defined_ so it won't set a new value for it; but for `$fn1 //= ...` the part `//` of the `//=` operator (is-it-defined) is false (`$fn1` has not been given) so it assigns `$fname[0]` for it.  Etc.

Comment: (the above uses the first example invocation, `script.pl --file2 name2`)

Comment: Your explanations always make the best sense!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there are three (or more) arguments and then set the variables from `@ARGV`. Otherwise first set them from the function and selectively overwrite the first and the second variable.

```
my ($file1, $file2, $file3);
if (scalar(@ARGV) >= 3) {
    ($file1, $file2, $file3) = @ARGV;
}
else {
    ($file1, $file2, $file3) = getFiles();
    if (scalar(@ARGV) >= 1) {
        $file1 = $ARGV[0];
    }
    if (scalar(@ARGV) >= 2) {
        $file2 = $ARGV[1];
    }
}
```

Or, if `getFiles()` isn't expensive, just first set them by the function and overwrite them if necessary.

```
my ($file1, $file2, $file3) = getFiles();
if (scalar(@ARGV) >= 1) {
    $file1 = $ARGV[0];
}
if (scalar(@ARGV) >= 2) {
    $file2 = $ARGV[1];
}
if (scalar(@ARGV) >= 3) {
    $file3 = $ARGV[2];
}
```

Comment: What is the reason behind checking if there is more than a certain number of arguments? Why check if there is more than 2 or 3?

Comment: @sfr: More `>= 3` is optional, you'd need to match more than three if you allowed more than three arguments. For the `>= 1`: The first variable needs to be overwritten if the first argument was given. When the first argument was given `@ARGV` contains at least one element but it can be more, if the second argument was also given. And analog for the other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
my @files = &getFileList();

my ($file1, $file2, $file3) = &getFileSubList();

print "file1 : $file1\n";
print "file2 : $file2\n";
print "file3 : $file3\n";



sub getFileSubList() {

    my @indeces = (0, 2, 3);
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $#indeces; $i++) {
        if ($ARGV[$i]) {
            $files[$indeces[$i]] = $ARGV[$i];
        }
    }   

    my ($file1, $file2, $file3);

    return ($file1, $file2, $file3) = ($files[0], $files[2], $files[3]);
}
```

just loop over @ARGV and assign any matching file to the return array at the appropriate index, and then return the three at (0,2,3)  of the resulting array.

Also note that you can get rid of the warnings you outlined by adding

```
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';
```

although in this case you actually want to see that the varz are uninitialized, they'll go away if the varz are populated properly.

I omitted the function that populates the initial array of files, I just globbed a folder on my file system.